# optional list argument "list = list or []" in python

Tags: python, list, immutability, optional-arguments

Conventional way of dealing with optional list arguments is the following:

```
def func(list_of_vals = None):
   if list_of_vals is None:
      list_of_vals = []
   ...
```

I wounder if the following (shorter) version has any pitfalls? why nobody do that? is it considered more obscure?

```
list_of_vals = list_of_vals or []
```

Comment: I do that, I think it's great. Decent python programmers will understand it. But using `l` as a variable name, that's bad.

Comment: @AlexHall , sure, that's just a sample piece of code to illustrate an idea

Comment: If someone explicitly passes an empty list, you create a new one. That may not be what they were expecting.

Comment: This is very common. It's standard in JS as well. In fact, default arguments in Typescript compile into the above code, but in JS. Anyone even remotely proficient in the language will know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The fact that an empty list in Python is falsely kind of throws a wrench in the pattern unfortunately.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It would only be an issue if the function is supposed to modify its input list in place. But if that's what the function does, it doesn't make sense for the argument to be optional.

Comment: @Barmar yes, if they're also following the *"either mutate **or** return"* pattern it should be fine

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is a great comment, you might want to put it as answer so that more people see it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern `if arg is None:` is usual, it is familiar to Python developers and has no weird edge cases.  **My recommendation is just stick with the convention**.

Your proposal using `or` logically deviates when `bool(list_of_vals) == False` but `list_of_vals is not None`, so I would recommend against doing that.

Another possible option is to "duck type" using an empty tuple:

```
def a(vals=()):
    ...
```

Because tuples are immutable, this has none of the pitfalls of the mutable default list. There are many use-cases where you only need to the input container to be indexable and iterable, so `vals` can happily remain as a tuple.

Comment: I feel like if type of typical values passed to function (`list`) differs from default value type (`tuple`), that might be even more misleading

Comment: This is an excellent idea. It won't work if the passed list is expected to be modified by the function (which would be strange for an optional argument), but otherwise it even suggests the immutability which is a plus.

Comment: @BenUsman A good Python function should care about the type of the argument as little as possible anyway.

Comment: `vals = vals if vals is not None else []` might be somewhere in between? (both short, readable and conventional)

Comment: "A good Python function should care about the type of the argument as little as possible anyway" ... unless it needs to do anything with the argument, and then it should care very much if it's an appropriate type to do it with :P

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases, you want that the list can be altered outside the function, then the second variant prevents calling `a` with:

```
some_list = []
a(some_list)
print(some_list)
```

If you want to prevent alternation of the list parameter, you should make a copy inside `a`

```
def a(l=()):
    l = list(l)
```